# is this SHA256 hashing formula correct?

Tags: php, hash, sha256

I am trying to implement Wonderlandpay payment in my website where they ask to hash a signature value using this formula

```
sha256(merNo + gatewayNo +orderNo + orderCurrency + orderAmount + cardNO + cardExpireYear + cardExpireMonth + cardSecurityCode + signkey );
```

So I translated in PHP using hash() method like this

```
hash("sha256", "99999 + 58697423 + d00001 + USD+ 600 +4111111111111111+2025+12+123+ 25648kjl3")
```

Unfortunately, when I try to submit the form I keep getting

> error I0013 Encryption value is incorrect

I tried to ask them about it, but they only told me that "The signature method is incorrect"
so I want to know if the hash function is correct or not and if there is another way to hash that value on php

Comment: Usually the data is concatenated without any additional characters (e.g. "9999958697423d00001USD...") and then hash the complete string

Comment: thank you this solved my problem